# extracting javascript rendered data from a web page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

What i need to accomplish in the end is

A. send a url to the form on this page: youtube-mp3.org

B. get the scr attribute of a link on the resulting page.

I'm  using Ruby on Rails and tried this method to send the request and get the body of the resulting page:

```
require 'uri'
yt_uri = URI('http://www.youtube-mp3.org')
params = { :id => "youtube-url" , :value => "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE" }
yt_uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(yt_uri)
res.body
```

and it works fine but the problem is that the website uses javascript to render the link so it is not showing up in the source. Instead I get

```
<noscript>
  <div class="warning">You have to enable JavaScript to use this Service!</div>
</noscript>
```

is there a way around this. Im open to any suggestions

Comment: Using robot scrappers to get this kind of information will get you blocked by the website. Because it's kind of rude.

Comment: Use something like WATIR or Selenium or PhantomJS

Comment: I dont see it as rude. All i'm really doing is automating a task for a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two routes:

- Actually execute the Javascript, and then do the scraping. This is heavyweight, both in terms of resources, in terms of work required
- Figure out what the Javascript in question is actually doing

In this case, it's pretty easy. Go to `http://www.youtube-mp3.org`, open up your browser's trusty network debugger, and use the web form. Now, go back and inspect the requests and responses.

In my case, there appear to be four calls to external elements:

- /a/pushitem
- rectangle.htm
- skyscraper.htm
- /a/iteminfo
- i.ytimg.com/vi/KMU0tzLwhbE

There's nothing interesting in the first three requests, but the fourth has some interesting looking JSON, and the last is a thumbnail image for the video.

The text from /a/iteminfo:

```
info = { "title" : "Developers", "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KMU0tzLwhbE/default.jpg", "length" : "3", "status" : "serving",  "progress_speed" : "",  "progress" : "",  "ads" : "",  "pf" : "",  "h" : "a0bb1715519025e36487b173b231295c"  };
```

And, for those following along at home, the link src jsamm is trying to ferret out:

```
http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&h=a0bb1715519025e36487b173b231295c&r=1380935176286
```

`video_id` is pretty easy to figure out- and we already have it. The `h` value came back in that JSON blob. `r` is a little more mysterious- but it looks remarkably like the current unix epoch + 3 extra digits. Oh wait- that's what Javascript's `Date.getTime()` gives you!

Anyway, don't do this. Not only are you being a jerk to whoever runs youtube-mp3.org, you're almost certainly violating the YouTube terms of service, and you're swimming in ugly copyright waters.

Comment: Thanks, that was great (my first post by the way). The last 3 numbers are random though so I think they almost fool proofed that approach. I found an api that I can do it in a matter of a simple URL. I learned a lot trying all these approaches though. Where is the line drawn on legal and illegal. As long as I don't host any of the content on my server I'll be fine right?

Comment: The last three digits indicate the millisecond at which the javascript was run. That whole field isn't even necessary- try taking it out, it still works.

As for legal vs illegal- maybe. The most important question is probably "will a lawyer ever notice you".

Comment: oh of course, I tried up voting but I couldn't, didn't know I could accept. Thanks, again.